# How to put a v-line in a histogram?

Tags: r

[image]

Hi everybody,

I tried to add a ver-line to this histogram for identify the density of a simulated networks with my observed data as the line should be on 0.124, by the code: `lines(rep(gden(friendnet),2),c(0,30),col="red",lwd=5)`

but I face error:

> Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : plot.new has not
>   been called yet
>
> Blockquote

Comment: abline(v= <xvalue of your choice)) ?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Show your code and data. This works just fine:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(100, .124, .015)
hist(x, ylim=c(0, 30))
lines(rep(.124, 2), c(0, 30))
```

[image]

Comment: True. I was copying his code to show that his error message suggests a problem in code that he did not include in his question, but as long as he wants to go to the top of the plot window, `abline` is easier.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments
I checked it again and the problem was not about the code itself
this error happen when you put the lines() function in another chunk.. Again Thanks for your support